# Get Text Symbol Programmatically With ID

Tags: abap

Is there any way of programmatically getting the value of a Text Symbol at runtime?

The scenario is that I have a simple report that calls a function module. I receive an exported parameter in variable `LV_MSG` of type `CHAR1`. This indicates a certain status message created in the program, for instance `F` (Fail), `X` (Match) or `E` (Error). I currently use a `CASE` statement to switch on `LV_MSG` and fill another variable with a short description of the message. These descriptions are maintained as text symbols that I retrieve at compile time with `text-MS#` where # is the same as the possible returns of `LV_MSG`, for instance `text-MSX` has the value "Exact Match Found".

Now it seems to me that the entire `CASE` statement is unnecessary as I could just assign to my description variable the value of the text symbol with ID `'MS' + LV_MSG` (pseudocode, would use `CONCATENATE`). Now my issue is how I can find a text symbol based on the String representation of its ID at runtime. Is this even possible?

If it is, my code would look cleaner and I wouldn't have to update my actual code when new messages are added in the function module, as I would simply have to add a new text symbol. But would this approach  be any faster or would it in fact degrade the report's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would probably define a domain and use the fixed values of the domain to represent the values. This way, you would even get around the string concatenation. You can use the function module `DD_DOMVALUE_TEXT_GET` to easily access the language-dependent text of a domain value.

To access the text elements of a program, use a function module like `READ_TEXT_ELEMENTS`.

Be aware that generic programming like this will definitely slow down your program. Whether it would make your code look cleaner is in the eye of the beholder - if the values change rarely, I don't see why a simple `CASE` statement should be inferior to some generic text access.

Comment: You make a good point, the domain approach seems to be SAP's equivalent of an enum and will be the approach I'll use in the future. And that function module seems to be just what I'd need if I wanted to replace the `CASE`. But as you say that approach has significant drawbacks, both in readability and performance.

Comment: It would be better to use a message class this if you are going to create something in the DDIC anyway. It really is a better means of communicating a message than domains since you will get an error type and number and it is supported everywhere in SAP.

Comment: @DW8Reaper: Splitting hairs there, but a message class is not part of the DDIC :-). And a message class is unsuitable if you have to map texts to arbitrary non-numeric values. The OP stated that the data is received from a function module - in this case you typically don't have any control over whether the function module uses a message class or not.

Comment: A message classes would indeed be preferred if my program was a simple report calling the function module only once. However, in my case I call my function module once for every record in an arbitrarily large data set. (`LV_MSG` then identifies the search depth of the underlying operation.) That value is converted to text and added to an internal table for output in a batch script (the report is for advanced users), so messages aren't really usable in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I understand you correctly but here goes. This is possible with a little trickery, all the text symbols in a report are defined as variables in the program (with the name text-abc where abc is the text ID). So you can use the following:

```
data: lt_all_text type standard table of textpool with default key,
      lsr_text    type ref to textpool.

"Load texts - you will only want to do this once
read textpool sy-repid into lt_all_text language sy-langu.
sort lt_all_Text by entry.

"Find a text, the field KEY is the text ID without TEXT-
read table lt_all_text with key entry = i_wanted_text
     reference into lsr_text binary search.
```

If you want the address you can add:

```
field-symbols: <l_text> type any.

data l_name type string.
data lr_address type ref to data.

concatenate 'TEXT-' lsr_text->key into l_name.
assign (l_name) to <l_text>.
if sy-subrc = 0.
  get reference of <l_text> into lr_address.
endif.
```

As vwegert pointed out this is probably not the best solution, for error handling rather use message classes or exception objects. This is useful in other cases though so now you know how.

Comment: Thank you for this code. As you say it's not the right approach for this scenario but I think this will be good to refer to in the future. You actually use a different approach than the `READ_TEXT_ELEMENTS` FM that vwegert referred to, which seems to use `LOAD REPORT`.